# Remove bibliography entry from ToC or change the way it is displayed

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, memoir

I'm using the `memoir` class and have my document structured by parts which means that the "Bibliography" entry in the Table of Contents are not showing correctly (I guess that it is shown as a chapter instead of as a part).

I see two solutions:

1. Remove the entry from the ToC and add a custom entry like

   `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Bibliography}`
2. Change the way the entry is shown by default

Does anyone know about a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine `\bibsection`; for example, to have the bibliography heading as one for a regular unnumbered part and to have the entry in the ToC formatted in the same way as part entries, you can do:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{%
\part*{\bibname}
\bibmark
\ifnobibintoc\else
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\bibname}
\fi
\prebibhook}
```

and then invoke

```
\bibintoc
```

Comment: What a very nice fix! The only thin is that the Bibliography gets its own part page, but the page doesn't say "Part XX Bibliography". Is it possible to somehow make that happen? Otherwise I would like that the Bibliography header is on the same page as the references - like default. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @thilemann sure! Change `\part*{\bibname}` to `\part{\bibname}` in the redefinition of `\bibsection`.

Comment: I get the following error: `LaTeX Error: \bibsection undefined`